# Can one tell interdental n, l, from alveolar n, l, by hearing?

Tags: pronunciation, phonemes

According to several well documented linguistic studies, a few languages like Mapudungun make a phonemic difference between interdental n, l, (let us spell it nd, ld), and a so called "alveolar n, l". Although I have no problem in producing those sounds, I am unable to hear the difference between them, so I wonder whether there are alternative explanations for that distinction, like (1) the sounds called 'alveolar' are rather retroflex, or (2) hearers *see* the difference by looking at the speakers face instead of *hearing* it. But if at least a few adults are able to hear the difference, I suppose that every child that is systematically exposed to such a distiction will surely hear it.

Is the human ear capable of perceiving or learning to perceive a phonetic difference between an interdental and an alveolar articulation of n and l?  And, since there might be no studies of that matter, do *you* hear any difference between an interdental and an alveolar articulation of n and l?

(Those sounds appear in almost all contexts, word-initially, either before or after one of the vowels e,a,o, i,ɘ,u, and word-finally)

Comment: I don't think it's a constructive question. Many people can tell them apart, many people can't. So what? If you have other questions, ask them explicitly.

Comment: @michau I think Goswin has had a good shot at being explicit there. I think it's a reasonable question.

Comment: I just looked at myself in the mirror pronouncing interdental l/n vs. alveolar l/n and I definitely can't *see* a difference, so I think (2) can be safely ruled out. On the other hand, I can hear a difference; it's pretty slight, but not so slight that your brain couldn't be trained to distinguish the sounds with practice.

Comment: Plenty of Australian languages have this contrast (as well as contrasting retroflex and lamino-palatal forms). Speakers have no trouble distinguishing them by hearing alone, and many non-native speakers (such as myself) have learned them.

Comment: Are you listening to them in isolation or in some context, like before or after an [a] vowel? Distinguishing them in the latter case will be much easier than in the former case, as the transitions going into and coming out of them will cue their respective places of articulation.

Comment: @Gaston - actually it might be a good point to try learning the contrast from speakers, whose languages actually distinguish them. E.g. my language is supposed to have alveolar n,l but with no contrast, that means it is *mostly* alveolar and there is some potentiality involved.

Comment: @michau: The fact that many people cannot tell them apart seems to me pretty obvious. I am of course interested in knowing whether _some_ people can tell them apart.

Comment: Given that this is a common phonemic contrast in Australia (probably at least scores of languages), there are many people who can tell them apart.

Comment: I vote to leave this question open because it's about whether the difference can be heard at all (so the answer would be yes as long as at least some people can hear it), disregarding the fact that some may find it harder.

Comment: @lemontree: My question is based on the following (hopefully correct) assumption: If **some adults**, not many but at least a few, are able to hear the difference, then **every child** that is systematically exposed to such a distiction will surely hear the difference.

Comment: @Goswin Yes, that's how I understood it.

Comment: @lemontree Asking if individual people can hear the difference is almost the *definition* of an opinion based question. This needs to be closed ASAP.

Comment: @curiousdannii No, this is not the definition of an opinion. Or is "How many people have been diagnosed with AIDS in 2016" opinion-based just because it's about individuals? The question here is "Is the human body in principle capable of perceiving (or learning to perceive) a phonetic difference between sounds x and y". I really don't see why this needs to be closed "ASAP".

Comment: @lemontree That would be an acceptable question, but this question is not that. This question asks "Do *you* hear any difference" This site is not a poll service.

Comment: @curiousdanni Oh, I see the problem. I understood the "Can *you*" as "Can *one*", especially with what Goswin added later, but the emphasis of "you" in the second paragraph does sound like a poll. Maybe Goswin could clarify that?

Comment: @lemontree Oh, I completely missed that the you could be taken as a generic you, Yeah clarification would be good, but it sure looks like a poll to me, and that's how two of the three answers have taken it.

Comment: Native English speakers can correct me if I'm wrong, but when "you" is in a question and additionally emphasised ("Do *you* hear any difference [...]"), I see no way of interpreting it as a generic you.

Comment: I am interested in an answer to the question as posed by curiousdannii: "Is the human body in principle capable of ...".  But I doubted the existence of relevant studies of that matter, and I was actually wondering whether anybody even _considered_ an alternative as visual perception. Thus I thought (possibly mistaken) that the only way to reach a practical conclusion was by doing a poll. So the question was meant as a poll, but in search of an objective answer.

Comment: @Goswin As explained by the other comments, if you want to make a poll, Stack Exchange is not the right place for it. If you re-word your question to "Are there any studies on this?" however, then it fits here, and then there might be additionally (!) indivudal comments like "I personally can/can not hear it", but that's not what you should put your focus on to stay in the scope of a Q&A site.

Comment: @lemontree: Even if some people who answered did answer to a poll, I consider that their **answers are definitely useful** since they do also answer to the intended inquiry (I now changed the wording). As we already agreed, "some adults" imply "all children".

Comment: @Goswin The answers may be useful for you, but that doesn't make the question useful for the site... The new wording is okay I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can hear the difference, and it's not based on seeing. The basic training method involves listening to minimal and near-minimal pairs, preferably using multiple speakers, multiple languages, and multiple words (the standard one speaker, one language, one pair is terrible for gaining the necessary experience). The [UCLA phonetics archive](http://archive.phonetics.ucla.edu/) will probably have a number of examples that you can listen to, to get the difference.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, several well-documented studies say it's a phonemic distinction in some languages. It answers your question: some people can tell them apart.

I don't see why you're looking for alternative explanations. I often hear from native English speakers that alveolo-palatal and retroflex consonants in my native Polish sound identical, while none of 40 mln Polish speakers have any problem in telling them apart (as long as they are not hard of hearing). On the other hand, I've been learning Mandarin for 10 years and I'm told that I pronounce tone distinctions reasonably well, but still have a problem with identifying the tone of an unknown word, even if it's pronounced clearly, but without emphasis. Again, for 1 bln Chinese speakers it is not a problem at all.

Comment: @ michau: Although several studies say it is a phonemic distinction in mapudungun, (1) some of those studies are over 100 years old, and (2) some other studies, working with different informants, were unable to detect such distinction.

Comment: @Goswin If you put this information into your question, and asked sth like "is there a phonemic distinction between interdental/alveolar n/l in Mapudungun?", I would have no objections at all. Anyway, it looks like you got the answer you wanted, so whatever.

Comment: Whether there is a phonemic distinction between interdental/alveolar n/l in Mapudungun seems to be somewhat controversial - or at least that is the impression I got. Many speakers may also be heavily influenced by the Spanish language, so great care has to be taken when choosing appropriate informants.

Answer (score 2):

I have a near minimal pair for dental versus alveolar t in my midwestern American English.  The difference is clearly audible to me -- perhaps if your speech is like mine in this respect, this might be helpful.  The pair is "tent" versus "tenth", i.e. [tʰɛ̃nt] versus [tʰɛ̃n̪t̪].

What has happened here is that the rather difficult cluster /nθ/ has been simplified by assimilating continuant [θ] to the preceding non-continuant [n], then the [n] assimilates regressively in position to the following dental stop.